# How to conditional format based on multiple specific text in Excel

Tags: excel, list, formatting, conditional-statements

I have a spreadsheet that i use to determine when/what clients to contact when an issue arises. in the first workbook i insert a column every day and paste in information about any questionable habits from clients, including a client ID. unfortunately the data i am copying from also includes clients that are not to be contacted during an issue. i have a second page that has listed in column A all of the "dont check" client ids. is there a way to conditional format the original page to color any cells referencing a "dont check" client based upon the don't check listing in sheet 2?

EDIT: there is more than just client ID in the first sheet cells. client id is just included. the format is [(last file received date)(Client Name)(Client ID)(Last X file received date) (Last Y file received date)] all in one cell.

In theory what i would like is to go to conditional formatting, highlight cell rules, text that contains... then select A1-A45 on Sheet2 and click okay. obviously this is not possible. an error shows up stating "this type of reference cannot be used in a Conditional Formatting formula. Change the reference to a single cell, or use the reference with a worksheet function such as =SUM(A1:E5)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: When you say, " the format is [(last file received date)(Client Name)(Client ID)(Last X file received date) (Last Y file received date)]" Do you mean those are the separate columns or all of that information is in one cell?

Comment: all of that info is in one cell, and i am using 2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `MATCH` for instance.

1. Select the column from the first cell, for example cell A2 to cell A100 and insert a conditional formatting, using 'New Rule...' and the option to conditional format based on a formula.
2. In the entry box, put:

   ```
   =MATCH(A2, 'Sheet2'!A:A, 0)
   ```
3. Pick the desired formatting (change the font to red or fill the cell background, etc) and click OK.

`MATCH` takes the value `A2` from your data table, looks into `'Sheet2'!A:A` and if there's an exact match (that's why there's a `0` at the end), then it'll return the row number.

**Note: Conditional formatting based on conditions from other sheets is available only on Excel 2010 onwards. If you're working on an earlier version, you might want to get the list of 'Don't check' in the same sheet.**

**EDIT**: As per new information, you will have to use some reverse matching. Instead of the above formula, try:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(SEARCH('Sheet2'!$A$1:$A$44, A2),0))
```

Comment: @user2890953 Updated answer with new formula.

Comment: When using this formula, it formats all entries except the don't check entries and some notes on the side. I flipped it to say "does not contain" and it highlights the correct cells but also highlights anything empty.

Comment: @user2890953 Are you using the "Use formula to determine which cells to format" option I was referring to in step 1?

Comment: I was. after deleting the rule and starting over it worked. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your "Don't Check" list is on Sheet2 in cells `A1:A100`, say, and your current client IDs are in Sheet1 in Column A.

What you would do is:

1. Select the whole data table you want conditionally formatted in Sheet1
2. Click `Conditional Formatting` > `New Rule` > `Use a Formula to determine which cells to format`
3. In the formula bar, type in `=ISNUMBER(MATCH($A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$100,0))` and select how you want those rows formatted

And that should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response... unfortunately that is not working...
not sure if it matters, but in sheet one there is more info than just the client ID in each cell, so it won't match exactly. but my list is from A1 to A44 on Sheet2.

Comment: That, unfortunately, makes an ENORMOUS difference - Please update your question with that and maybe put in some sample data - Otherwise we can't really help here.